# Swift wildcard in generics

Tags: generics, swift, wildcard

The project I'm currently working on uses a lot of generics. I'm having a problem when attempting to use wildcards.

In Java I can do:

```
public class testGeneric<T> {

}
public class testing {
    public <T> void test (testGeneric<T> input) {
          testGeneric<?> testOne = input;
    }
}
```

Without any errors.

In Swift I was using AnyObject (as it was meant to be the base of all objects, so I assumed it would be usable in the same way).

However, the following throws errors (specifically "T is not identical to AnyObject"):

```
class testGeneric<T> {

}

class testing {
    func test <T> (input: testGeneric<T>) {
        var testOne: testGeneric<AnyObject> = input
    }
}
```

After searching around a bit I found that there are "Wildcard patterns" in Swift (specifically "_ "). However, this doesn't seem to work for generics.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `AnyObject` does not include structs and primitives. You could try `Any` instead which everything except for functions conforms to, but I'm not sure that will work

Comment: @connor I have tried using Any, unfortunately it has the same problem.

Comment: yeah. you may want to try a cast instead. `if let var testOne: testGeneric<Any> = input as? testGeneric<Any> { /*code */ }` Note that does mean it won't work if T is a function type

Comment: @connor Unfortunately casting throws the same error. Thanks for taking the time to think about it though

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Pass any instance of testGeneric into testing?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
class testGeneric<T> {
}

class testing {
    func test <T> (input: testGeneric<T>) {
        var testOne: testGeneric<T> = input
    }
}
```